# Using Symbols while coding

Tags: symbols

What does the different symbols mean when coding? such as * < > != # and why are they needed? how do I know which ones to use. and Which words to use to begin a code like including a save option? I have read the course work downloaded additional Wiki docs. Python.org tutorials and I have not found any answers to my questions.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is very broad. From your question it looks like you are still learning the syntax of your programming language. You may benefit more from reading a book or using a tutorial. Happy coding!

Comment: Yes, i agree and this is supposed to be beginners programming. Hummm? don't sound like beginners to me. Thank you kindly for your response. 4castle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are called operators, and they perform some operation on the values associated with them (known as operands). For example, 1 * 2 means to multiply (operator *) 1 and 2 (the operands) and return the product.

You should seek more intensive programming education before attempting to implement a save option. Your question is very basic and indicates that you are still learning the basics. Keep at it! The greatest writers of all time once had to spend time learning their ABC's and how to sound out words.